# Postgres is throwing errors about prepared statements

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm

I'm seeing a lot of the same errors in my Postgres log related to prepared statements for a specific application. There are several application using the same DB instance and none of those are having issues.  I don't know why it is happening or if I should be worried about it. Functionally the PHP application is running fine.

I have pgbouncer running in front of the DB.

```
< 2017-03-23 05:15:01.663 CDT >ERROR:  prepared statement "pdo_stmt_00000001" already exists
< 2017-03-23 05:15:01.663 CDT >STATEMENT:  SELECT DISTINCT a0_.company_id AS company_uuid0, a0_.sub_source AS sub_source1, a0_.notification_body AS notification_body2, a0_.system_id AS system_id3 FROM action_item_notification a0_ WHERE a0_.delivered = false
< 2017-03-23 05:15:01.664 CDT >ERROR:  prepared statement "pdo_stmt_00000001" does not exist
< 2017-03-23 05:15:01.664 CDT >STATEMENT:  DEALLOCATE pdo_stmt_00000001
```

Comment: The client that throws the error trying to create prepared statement within the same session over again, that's why it fails. It needs to DEALLOCATE (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-deallocate.html) or not re-create prepared statement over again within the ongoing session. But IMHO it makes more sense to use stored procedure instead.

Comment: It is a bug in the PHP application. That's where you have to look.

Comment: Thanks for responding.